# Cardinality of Natural Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

New to Mathexchange, here with my first question!

I've recently learnt about set theory and sets, I wanted to know if the set of 'Natural Numbers' starting at zero would be greater in cardinality (size) than the same set starting at one.

Comment: For further reading, your example is more-or-less the same as "Hilbert's Hotel". See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel

Comment: Thank you, That has really interested me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of natural numbers including $0$, which is $$\{0,1,2,3,\,...\}$$ has the exact same cardinality as the set of natural numbers excluding $0$, which is $$\{1,2,3,4,\,...\}$$

---

This is because two sets that have a one-to-one correspondence between them must have the same cardinality.

You can explicitly write out one such correspondence as follows:

$$0 \,\longleftrightarrow\, 1$$
$$1 \,\longleftrightarrow\, 2$$
$$2 \,\longleftrightarrow\, 3$$
$$3 \,\longleftrightarrow\, 4$$
$$4 \,\longleftrightarrow\, 5$$
$$\text{etc.}$$